# SharePoint rest interface is slow for a particular list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, rest

I have about 10 list in my SharePoint site.

I am using REST to query some data. However, I have got an irritating issue.

I have lists called, Applications(3000 Items), Candidates(30000 Items), Vacancies(2000) items.

When I try to query Applications and Candidates, the query is so quick. However, even though Vacancies list has much less items in it, and I select only 2 fields, it takes about 15 seconds, and my query only returns 260 items.

I am trying to find out why REST query takes longer for a specific list. I dont know where to look at as it is a bot black box for me now.

any idea why this is behaving like this?

thanks

Comment: How many columns the lists have?

Comment: Around 40, but not all of them are queried. If you do not specify in the $select part of the REST query, would it still query them?

Comment: how many of them are lookup fields?

Comment: Only 2, and 8 of them Person Or Group if you consider it as Lookup...

Comment: Check fiddler to see the details of the rest query and to debug what is taking time.

Comment: Make a test using the "$select=title, ID" in you REST consult, if the performance is satisfactory, then insert the other columns you need.

Comment: Changing number of the columns I query does not make any difference...

Comment: Apparently, a multiple choice field makes the query slow... But I do not know what the issue is with this field..

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this issue has been resolved.

I removed an unused field and it started to perform as is used to perform.

However, I am not sure why deletion of a random file resolved the performance problem. I would love to tell the reason, but I really do not know.

I am also not sure whether my answer is a real answer..

Comment: This is possible. One of the reasons might be _row wrapping_. SharePoint stores items from all lists in a single database table. This table has a fixed number of columns for each field type. If you exceed those numbers SharePoint uses 2 rows in DB for each item and must `JOIN` them. Removing one field may do the difference here.

Comment: And it started to happen again:(.... annoying... it is slow again...

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if you got any farther on this. I had the same issue, but it was taking 1 min and 30 sec. I removed a field and it was much faster. Please post back if you ended up finding a long-term fix.

Comment: And my list has only 107 items in it...